# PHP: How to access array element values using array-index

Tags: php, arrays

How to access array element values using array-index?

```
<?
$json = '{
    "dynamic":{
       "pageCount":"12",
       "tableCount":"1"
    }
}';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

echo $arr['dynamic']['pageCount']; // working
echo $arr[0]['pageCount']; // not working
?>
```

I will not know what is there in 'dynamic', so i want to access pageCount values dynamically?

Comment: `foreach` will iterate over the array, providing both keys and values. `reset` will return the first value regardless of key (you can also get the key with `key`). `array_values` will replace the keys with auto-incrementing integers. What exactly is your use case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[array_values](http://php.net/array_values) is function you are looking for

Examples:

```
<?php
$json = '{
    "dynamic":{
       "pageCount":"12",
       "tableCount":"1"
    }
}';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);
echo $arr['dynamic']['pageCount']; // working

$arr = array_values($arr);
echo $arr[0]['pageCount']; // NOW working

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($value['pageCount'])) {
        //do something with the page count
    }
}
```

If the structure is always a single nested JS object:

```
$obj = current($arr);
echo $obj['pageCount'];
```

Comment: OK, got it working. But was thinking if there is direct access without loops

Comment: @ShivaramAllva: It can be so direct that it hurts: `extract(reset($arr));`. As I said in the comment -- what's the use case?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a non-looping solution that will work only if the structure is always a single nested JS object as in the example.