# Unable to access $data values in Controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("panTab");         
$this->db->where("QCJobPanelTestId = ",$TestId);
$query = $this->db->get();
$data['get_JobPan_Data'] = $query->result();

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data['get_JobPan_Data']);$i++)
{
$table = "Form1";
$whereField1 = "QC1TestId";
$whereField2 = "QC1JobPanelId";
$currDiv = "form1";
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from($table);
$this->db->where($whereField1." = ",$TestId); 
$this->db->where($whereField2." = ",$data['get_JobPan_Data'][$i]['QCJobPanelId']); //--This value gives an error . How to access it?
$query1 = $this->db->get();
$data['getTestData'] = $query1->result();
}
```

Data that is coming

```
 Array ( 
        [get_JobPan_Data] => Array ( 
            [0] => stdClass Object( 
                [QCJobPanelId] => 293 [QCJobPanelNo] => 1 
                [QCJobPanelDesc] => Pan 1 
                [QCJobPanelJobId] => 3 
                [QCJobPanelPanelId] => 0 
                [QCJobPanelTestId] => 63 
            ) 
            [getTestData] => Array ( 
                [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                    [QC1Id] => 77 
                    [QC1JobId] => 3 
                    [QC1TestId] => 63 
                    [QCTestDesc] => 0 
                    [QC1DielectricACC_LC] => 0 
                    [QC1DielectricACC_IRA] => 0 
                    [QCRemark] => Completed 
                    [QCTestedBy] => aa 
                    [QCReviewedBy] => bb 
                    [QCWitnessedBy] => cc 
                    [QC1JobPanelId] => 293 
                    [QCTestCompletionDate] => 2016-07-29 00:00:00 
                    [QC1DateAdded] => 2016-07-29 
                ) 
           )
        )
```

Also unable to get value from `$data['getTestData']`:
Tried with :

1. `$data['getTestData'][0]['TestDesc']`
2. `$data['getTestData'][0][0]['TestDesc']`
3. `$data['getTestData']['TestDesc']`

Comment: what is the output of $query1. Is it an array or object. Please check that

Comment: How to check that?

Comment: `$this->db->where("QCJobPanelTestId = $TestId");`

Comment: try debugging `var_dump($data);` and see the format of `$data`

Comment: Its an Array.. How to access it?

Comment: @VDS  can you show that array to us? `echo "<pre/>";print_r($data);` do it and paste your result in your question

Comment: Array
(
[get_JobPan_Data] => Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[QCJobPanelId] => 293
[QCJobPanelNo] => 1
[QCJobPanelDesc] => Pan 1
[QCJobPanelJobId] => 3
[QCJobPanelPanelId] => 0
[QCJobPanelTestId] => 63
)
[getTestData] => Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[QC1Id] => 77
[QC1JobId] => 3
[QC1TestId] => 63
[QCTestDesc] => 0
[QC1DielectricACC_LC] => 0
[QC1DielectricACC_IRA] => 0
[QCRemark] => Completed
[QCTestedBy] => aa
[QCReviewedBy] => bb
[QCWitnessedBy] => cc
[QC1JobPanelId] => 293
[QCTestCompletionDate] => 2016-07-29 00:00:00
[QC1DateAdded] => 2016-07-29
)
)
)

Comment: then use $data['getTestData'][0]->['TestDesc'] to get data

Comment: refer the below link for more deatils. Your output is standard objec output. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168422/how-to-access-a-property-of-an-object-stdclass-object-member-element-of-an-arr

Comment: @Anish - It worked fine only small change required is:$data['getTestData'][0]->TestDesc... Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to access $data including help from @Anish & @Anant :

- $data['getTestData'][0]->TestDesc
- ResultVariable[Array1][Array2]->Object variable

In short: 
 - If Array, then use []
 - If Object, then use ->

Answer (score 0):

yes there is mistake to access object

```
$this->db->where($whereField2." = ",$data['get_JobPan_Data'][$i]['QCJobPanelId']);
```

replace it with

```
$this->db->where($whereField2." = ",$data['get_JobPan_Data'][$i]->QCJobPanelId);
```