# Parsing Array to string

Tags: php, json

I have an object array which has key values

```
Array ( [0] =>stdClass Object ( [privacy] => {"name": "on", "email": null, "mobile": null, "address": "on", "alt_contact": "on"} ) )
```

I need to print a string which will contain the comma separated keys which has values as 'on'. The resultant string should be

```
$result = "name,address,alt_contact";
```

Please help

Comment: Hope it's a duplicate question. check the answer using this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168422/how-to-access-a-property-of-an-object-stdclass-object-member-element-of-an-arr

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick for you ..

```
$json = '{"name": "on", "email": null, "mobile": null, "address": "on", "alt_contact": "on"}';
$array = json_decode($json,true);

$str = "";
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
    if($value == "on")
        $str .= $key.",";
}
return rtrim($str,",");
```

> result:- name,address,alt_contact

Answer (score 0):

This is how your request translates to PHP:

> I need to
>
> - print - [echo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)
> - a string which will contain the comma separated - [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)
> - keys which has values as 'on' - [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

This is the code, straight from the list above:

```
$json = '{"name": "on", "email": null, "mobile": null, "address": "on", "alt_contact": "on"}';
// Pass TRUE as second argument to get arrays back; stdObject is useless
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

// print comma separated keys of 'on'
echo(implode(',', array_keys($data, 'on')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jaimin, It helped

Had to get the $privacy object parsed in an array as

```
$userPrivacies = $userPrivacies[0]->privacy;
```

and used your code later.

so the solution becomes

```
$userPrivacies = $userPrivacies[0]->privacy;

$array = json_decode($userPrivacies,true);

$str = "";
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
   if($value == "on")
      $str .= $key.",";
}
echo rtrim($str,",");
```

Comment: if my answer worked for you, you should select my answer as accepted.. it is a way of appreciation on stackoverflow...