# ErrorException htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I want to get data "report_to" from database. But i got error when I try to print variable in my view page. It's said "ErrorException
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given".

This is my controller.

```
function editroledetails(Request $request)
    {
        $user = \Auth::user();
        $userphone = 0;
        $reportTo = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT report_to FROM customer_type WHERE username='19331986' "));
        $data = [
            'editUsername' => $request->editUsername,
            'editNik' => $request->editNik,
            'editEmail' => $request->editEmail,
            'editRegIdentities' => $request->editRegIdentities,
            'editID' => $request->editID
        ];

        return view('editroledetails', compact('user', 'userphone', 'data', 'reportTo'));
    }
```

This is my view

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
            <h3>{{$reportTo}}</h3>
        </div>
```

I expect the view will display the variable that is "Name", but I got error htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.

Comment: Well, the solution is in the error...you are passing an array instead of a string.

Comment: There is no `htmlspecialchars` in the code you posted

Comment: `reportTo` is array, either iterate over it in template, or extract one value in controller.

Comment: add error screen shot for more information

Comment: @Andreas It's implicit in the `{{ ... }}` template syntax.

Comment: Can you share the content of $reportTo (Maybe via `dd($reportTo);`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]
Thank you for the answer, Im already solved it.

This the code

```
<?php echo $reportTo[0]->report_to; ?>
```

[This is print_r of $reportTo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCKZL.jpg)

[This is my reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168422/how-to-access-a-property-of-an-object-stdclass-object-member-element-of-an-arr/21168507)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$reportTo = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT report_to FROM customer_type WHERE username='19331986' "));
```

to

```
$reportTo = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT report_to FROM customer_type WHERE username='19331986' "))->get();
```

and now `$reportTo` is an array you may need to use `@foreach` or `@for`. or if you are sure you will get only one record, you can use `first()` like

```
$reportTo = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT report_to FROM customer_type WHERE username='19331986' "))->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

it means and it is clear that $reportTo is a results set of the query, change your query to `$reportTo = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT report_to FROM customer_type WHERE username='19331986' "))->first();` and then access your DB column like $reportTo['colname']

Comment: I try that, and its show error "FatalErrorException Call to a member function first() on array"