# Iterate through multidimensional object/array

Tags: php, arrays, object, soap, iteration

I have some data out of a soap api. This data comes in this format:

```
array(2) {
  ["Request"]=>
  object(stdClass)#7 (3) {
    ["AccessKey"]=>
    string(3) "dub"
    ["Timestamp"]=>
    string(19) "2019.07.04 09:06:19"
    ["Conditions"]=>
    object(stdClass)#8 (1) {
      ["Condition"]=>
      object(stdClass)#9 (2) {
        ["Field"]=>
        string(11) "From"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(10) "1562223979"
      }
    }
  }
  ["Products"]=>
  object(stdClass)#10 (1) {
    ["Product"]=>
    array(10) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#11 (11) {
        ["Ean"]=>
        string(13) "4029759107323"
        ["Type"]=>
        string(9) "DVD"
        ["Title"]=>
        string(58) "Hellraisers"
        ["FSK"]=>
        string(36) "Freigegeben ohne Altersbeschränkung"
        ["Genre"]=>
        string(5) "Sport"
        ["Year"]=>
        string(4) "2015"
        ["Length"]=>
        string(3) "275"
        ["Language"]=>
        string(7) "Deutsch"
        ["Items"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["Release"]=>
        string(10) "2049-12-31"
        ["Label"]=>
        string(17) "Edel Germany GmbH"
      }
```

I want to loop through this data and get the title of every set.

I tried a foreach loop, but I get some error messages.

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo "Titel " . $result->Titel;
}
```

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo "Titel " . $result['Product']->Titel;
}
```

Nothing works. I can't wrap my head around arrays...

Comment: By `Titel` you mean `Title`? As you desire output for that example will be "Hellraisers"?

Comment: As the data looks as though it is under another element - try `foreach ($results['Products'] as $result) {` in your last effort.  (along with the correct spelling).

Comment: The 2 objects in the resulting array seem very different. I don't think a loop would be the best way to get these results.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! @Nigel When i try this, i get Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /opt/lampp/htdocs/api_test/index.php:39
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/api_test/index.php on line 39

Comment: @Dirk What other way can i try?

Comment: can you print whole response that you have got from API?

Comment: That because `$results['Products']` is object with attribute "Product" which doesn't make sense as it should be array...

Comment: The whole print is too long for the comment section

Comment: Notice:  Undefined index: Product in /opt/lampp/htdocs/api_test/index.php on line 40



Notice:  Trying to get property 'Title' of non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/api_test/index.php on line 40

Titel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't grasp something, sometimes its better to try to make it small and grow from there, start trying to print the entire response, then the property products, then product and then the product array:

#### How to reach the products array inside `$response`

First you have an object `$response` has elements with objects inside, `["Products"]` is the one we want, so `$response->Products` then inside `["Products"]` there is an object, with one property with the name of `["Product"]` that contains the array of objects with all the products, so `$response>Products->Product`. As `$response->Products->Product` is an array we need to iterate it, you iterate like this:

```
foreach($response->Products->Product as $product){
 echo $product->Title; // prints the title of every product
}
```

Don't hesitate to ask if you don't understand or it is not working, but by the code you pasted I thing the `foreach` is correct.

[How to access a property of an object (stdClass Object) member/element of an array? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21168507/9724551)

#### JSON format advice

By the way, the JSON is not "clear" and "correct", the array of products should be one level above. Inside "Products" and not inside "Product".

Comment: Hey Josep! Thank you very much for the good process explanation.It helps me understand it a little bit better.

When I try your approach, I get this error message: Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /opt/lampp/htdocs/api_test/index.php:39
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/api_test/index.php on line 39

If try the Products as an object ($response->Products['Product'] i get the same message

I just get data from the api, i didnt write it myself. This is the JSON I get from it

Comment: @youwhatmate try `echo $product->Title`, instead of echo $product['Title']; . If it is not working use the next code `foreach($response["Products"]->Product as $product){
 echo $product->Title; // prints the title of every product
}`

Comment: Ok after some Trial&Error I got my result :-)
foreach($response->Products->Product as $product) { 
 echo $product->Title . "<br>";
}

Comment: @youwhatmate as you did not put the entire code I did not know that the main array was also an object, I'll edit the code, mark as right then, thanks!

Comment: Sorry for that! I marked your answer as the right one! Thank you!