# How can I access Json information in php using array indexing

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to get all prices and add them. I was planning on using this to loop through the JSON but that would be another question. Am I approaching this the wrong way? Is there a better way to get the SUM of all prices?

I have found this answer which makes the same question but it does not work (duplicate: [PHP: How to access array element values using array-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277268/php-how-to-access-array-element-values-using-array-index)). Here is my JSON string.

```
{
  "data": {
    "230723": {
      "2019-11-15": {
        "price": 52,
        "min_length_of_stay": 2,
        "available": 1
      },
      "2019-11-16": {
        "price": 90,
        "min_length_of_stay": 2,
        "available": 0
      },
      "2019-11-17": {
        "price": 44,
        "min_length_of_stay": 2,
        "available": 0
      },
      "2019-11-18": {
        "price": 44,
        "min_length_of_stay": 2,
        "available": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my code:

```
$resultJson =  file_get_contents('http://....');

$priceRange = json_decode($resultJson, true);
echo $priceRange['data']['230723']['2019-11-15']['price'];  // working

//$priceRange = array_values($priceRange);
echo $priceRange[0][0][0][0]; // not working
```

The first echo works and return 52. The second echo does not work with or without the commented line (which was the answer to the duplicate question).

What am I missing?

Comment: You would have to apply `array_values()` at each level of the array.

Comment: Would I have to use a loop for that? Could you elaborate a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: `echo $priceRange[0][0][0][0]; // not working` – why _should_ it work, what do you need this for? _If_ you actually applied array_values recursively, then you would lose the info currently contained in those keys completely - so you don’t need `230723` and the actual date values on the next level at all …?

Comment: I want to get all prices and add them. I was planning on using this to loop through the json but that would be another question. Am I approaching this the wrong way? Is there a better way to get the SUM of all prices?

Comment: Really!?!?.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the array from associative to numeric just loop through already existing array

### Like this

```php
$sum = 0;
$resultJson =  file_get_contents('http://....');

$priceRanges = json_decode($resultJson, true);
foreach ($priceRanges['data'] as $id => $priceRange) {
    if (!is_array($priceRange)) {
        continue;
    }
    foreach ($priceRange as $date => $priceInfo) {
        $sum += (isset($priceInfo['price']) ? intval($priceInfo['price']) : 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not get your code to work but I used it to write the following code (*see my own answer). It returns the sum but how bad is it concerning time complexity?

Comment: @Gluxable I was missing one closing parentheses `)` I edited my answer, should be fine now

Answer (score 1):

Well you know I hope that the data is in `data` and if you don't know the next key then `reset` helps.  Then just get all `price` keys (hopefully you know this as well) and sum them:

```
$result = array_sum(array_column(reset($array['data']), 'price'));
```

Another way is using `array_values` on the first two levels:

```
$result = array_sum(array_column(array_values(array_values($array)[0])[0], 'price'));
```

To get each price the way you were trying to do you would need:

```
$result = array_values(array_values(array_values(array_values($array)[0])[0])[0])[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I wrote using [Krzysztof Janiszewski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8790406/krzysztof-janiszewski) answer, and works.

```
$sum = 0;

$priceRange = json_decode($resultJson, true);

foreach($priceRange as $item) {
    foreach($item as $item2){
        foreach($item2 as $item3){
            $sum += $item3['price'];    
        }
    }
}

echo $sum;
```

Comment: This will work, but there is no fail safe. If something changes (or some elements lacks a value) your code will crush.